# Bringing an image to the front

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgflayers

I am trying to recreate diagrams like the screenshot below. However, when I do it in `tikz`, it seems to place it in the background or somewhere behind the triangular lines. I've tried placing the code elsewhere, or add in the `\pgfdeclarelayer{}` commands, but it doesn't seem to fix it at all. I also cannot rotate the orbitals too efficiently, such as the dz2 orbitals to make the screenshot. Is there a way to add rotational parameters to these? Please help.

Image:

[image]

NWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikzorbital}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,backgrounds,fit,arrows}
\pgfdeclarelayer{backbackground}
\pgfsetlayers{backbackground,background,main}

\tikzset{dz2/.pic={code=\orbital[pos={(0,0)},pcolor={red},ncolor={blue}]{dz2};}}
\tikzset{dxy/.pic={code=\orbital[pos={(0,0)},pcolor={red},ncolor={blue}]{dxy};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
\draw[thick,color=black!50] (-1,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,-1.75) -- cycle;
\draw[thick,color=black!50] (0,0) -- (-0.5,-0.875) -- (0.5,-0.875) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\path (A) pic[scale=0.75]{dxy};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tikzorbital` package seems to do the drawing on the `background` layer.  Placing the triangle on the `backbackground` layer (which is defined to be below the `background`) seems to work:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikzorbital}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,backgrounds,fit,arrows}
\pgfdeclarelayer{backbackground}
\pgfsetlayers{backbackground,background,main,foreground}


\tikzset{dz2/.pic={code=\orbital[pos={(0,0)},pcolor={red},ncolor={blue}]{dz2};}}
\tikzset{dxy/.pic={code=\orbital[pos={(0,0)},pcolor={red},ncolor={blue}]{dxy};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\path (A) pic[scale=0.75]{dxy};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{backbackground}
\draw[thick,color=black!50] (-1,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,-1.75) -- cycle;
\draw[thick,color=black!50] (0,0) -- (-0.5,-0.875) -- (0.5,-0.875) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```